# How to configure dynamically a datasource in spring project for multiple environments

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i'm working in a spring project with hibernate.. and all works fine in my local environment, but now i want to deploy my app to test environment and make my app connect to a new database (new url ,new username,new password)
this is the configuration of my datasource

```
<bean name="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db" />
    <property name="username" value="my_local_username" />
    <property name="password" value="my_local_password" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.fr.business.entites" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
</property>
```

my question is : how i can get the value of the properties (url,username,and password) dynamically according to the environment where i will deploy my app.

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple profiles like (dev, test, ist and so on) and use them with you Spring Based Application. That's an ideal way to develop, test and deploy your application since all the configuration are controlled via property files without a need to do any hardcoding in the code/applicaton.xml as such.

A nice article on how to do that can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)